# Best way to find the index of a match between two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python, but I am trying to find a function / method similar to the %in% function in R. I need to be able to return the matches of a list, to a list of lists. For example:

```
match = [1,2,3]
list = [[1,2,3], [1,5,2], [1,4], [15,1,8]]

function(match, list)
```

Which would return `0`, ideally, but `[True False False False]` is good enough too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like this:

```
[sublist == match for sublist in lst]
```

Or to obtain the index of the first matching sub-list, you can use the `list.index` method:

```
lst.index(match)
```

Note that the above method would raise a `ValueError` if `match` is not found in `lst`, so you should enclose it in a `try` block to handle the exception properly:

```
try:
    index = lst.index(match)
except ValueError:
    print('match not found')
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! How could I convert this into a usable slice though? For example: ```[True, False]``` into ```0```